# Align divs under each other

Tags: html, css, alignment

Basically I want align the `.answer` div under each other.

The text is now like this:

Firstname:       Oliver
Lastname:         Malan
Gender:        Male

And I want it to be like this:

Firstname:    Oliver
Lastname:     Malan
Gender:         Male

CODE:

```css
.profile-data {
  padding-left: 170px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
h3.header-h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
}
.data {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 60%;
}
.answer {
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="profil-data">

  <h3 class="header-h3">Personal Info</h3>

  <div class="data">
    Name:
    <div class="answer"><b>Oliver</b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="data">
    Lastname:
    <div class="answer"><b>Malan</b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="data">
    Gender:
    <div class="answer"><b>Male</b>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the text in a element, such as `label` and give a `width`

```css
label {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block
}
.profile-data {
  padding-left: 170px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
h3.header-h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
}
.data {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 60%;
}
.answer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="profil-data">

  <h3 class="header-h3">Personal Info</h3>

  <div class="data">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <div class="answer"><b>Oliver</b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="data">
    <label>Lastname:</label>
    <div class="answer"><b>Malan</b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="data">
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <div class="answer"><b>Male</b>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```