# How to align boxes right under each other with flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

The point is that I want to implement this layout with html, css and js.
When you click on the button, the container should alternately become taller/smaller.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nojeS.png)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D7SP.png)

- However, no fixed height should be passed, as is currently implemented.
  Without using max-height, scaleY.
- Also, text5 should be right under text2 and text6 right under text3 (as you can see in the picture) without using width or something similar.
  The **flex items should only be as large as the content**.

I've also searched for solutions, but the search results weren't what I was looking for.

[How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

[Flexbox not giving equal width to elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066214/flexbox-not-giving-equal-width-to-elements)

[Align divs under each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502379/align-divs-under-each-other)

```js
let isOpen = false;

function toggleHeight() {
    let row2 = document.getElementById('row2');
  if(!isOpen){
    isOpen= !isOpen;
    row2.style.height = '120px';
    //row2.style.height = 'auto';
  }
  else{
    isOpen= !isOpen;
    row2.style.height = '0';
  }

}
```

```css
.row1, .row2 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.row2 {
  height: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col1 {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="toggleHeight()">Click Me</div>

<div class="row1">
  <div class="col1">
      <div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>       
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>       
      </div>
       <div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>       
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div>text2</div>
      <div>text2</div>
  </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div>text3</div>
      <div>text3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="row2" class="row2">
  <div class="col1">
      <div>text4</div>
      <div>text4</div>
  </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div>text5</div>
      <div>text5</div>
  </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div>text6</div>
      <div>text6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _fixed height should not be passed_ even for show/hide??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created exactly you wanted but the transition on `height` is not working!

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const row2 = document.querySelector('#row-2')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  row2.classList.toggle('visible')
})
```

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css";
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

button {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

.flex {
  margin-top: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex .row {
  display: inherit;
  column-gap: 16px;
}

.flex .row .col {
  display: inherit;
  padding-inline: 16px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex .row#row-2 {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  transition: height 250ms ease, overflow 250ms ease;
}

.flex .row#row-2.visible {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Click Me!</button>

  <div class="flex">
    <div class="row" id="row-1">
      <div class="col">
        <span>texttexttext</span>
        <span>texttexttext</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>text2</span>
        <span>text2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>text3</span>
        <span>text3</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="row-2">
      <div class="col" style="align-self: center;">texttexttext</div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>text5</span>
        <span>text5</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <span>text6</span>
        <span>text6</span>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

P.S - remove `padding-inline` from `.col`.